# Referencing a dataframe object's index and column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. I want to create a new dataframe based on the column and index of elements, but I am unable to reference to their index name.

```
   AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD
A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Code:

```
df_ind = {'A' : '2014' ,'B': '2011' , 'C': '2007' , 'D' : '2009'}
df_col = {'AAA': '2011' ,'BBB': '2015' , 'CCC': '2007' , 'DDD' : '2012'}
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(index = df_ind.keys() , columns =df_col.keys()  )
print df_tmp    
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.where( int(df_col[df_tmp.column]-df_ind[tmp_df.index]) >1 , True, False) ,  index = df_ind.keys() , columns =df_col.keys()   )
print df4
```

Basically, I want to make elements with difference between dates of their columns and indices less than 2 year as True except false.

Edit1 : modified problem to clarify it .

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, but try `df_tmp.loc['B','AAA'] = 'green'` and see if that's that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df_tmp.ix['B', 'AAA'] = 'green'
df_tmp.fillna('red', inplace=True)
print (df_tmp)
     AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD
A    red  red  red  red
B  green  red  red  red
C    red  red  red  red
D    red  red  red  red
```

EDIT:

```
import pandas as pd


df_ind = {'A' : '2014' ,'B': '2011' , 'C': '2007' , 'D' : '2009'}
df_col = {'AAA': '2011' ,'BBB': '2015' , 'CCC': '2007' , 'DDD' : '2012'}
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(index = df_ind.keys() , columns =df_col.keys()  )
df_tmp.index = df_tmp.index.sort_values()
print (df_tmp)
   AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD
A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

```
#original df to df_orig
df_orig = df_tmp.copy()

#replace column and index name to values of dictionaries
df_tmp.columns = df_tmp.columns.map(df_col.get).astype(int)
df_tmp.index = df_tmp.index.map(df_ind.get).astype(int)
print (df_tmp)
     2011 2015 2007 2012
2014  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2011  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2007  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

#fill NaN values by column names
df_tmp = df_tmp.fillna(df_tmp.columns.to_series())

#substract index values from all dataframe
df = df_tmp.sub(df_tmp.index.to_series(), axis=0)
#replace original names
df.columns = df_orig.columns
df.index =  df_orig.index
print (df)
   AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD
A   -3    1   -7   -2
B    0    4   -4    1
C    4    8    0    5
D    2    6   -2    3

#compare by condition
print (df > 1)
     AAA    BBB    CCC    DDD
A  False  False  False  False
B  False   True  False  False
C   True   True  False   True
D   True   True  False   True
```

Comment: Ok, can you add data to your dataframe and desired output? Because I dont understand  `print (df_col[df_tmp.column])` - it return `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'`

Comment: that is the same issue I am facing , I somehow need to creae a Boolean table with given vertical and horizontal products and fill it up with True or false depending upon condition that the difference between the date of their product is less than 1 year , if there are some other ways to do this apart from dataframe , please do suggest them too.

Comment: Yes, so you need dataframes with columns `2007` to `2014` and with rows `2007` to `2015`? And instead `NaN` are some values? Sorry, but I still dont understand.

Comment: @jezarel as you can see my df_tmp is an empty dataframe with indices and columns , I want to fill this empty dataframe with True or false depending upon each element's index and columns correspoding dates so for example the required df4 will look something like this  https://bpaste.net/show/9cd358e3cfbc

Comment: Hmmm, I have idea, give me some time.

Comment: please see edit, but output is lettle different as you get in `bpaste`. Can you cach it? Is there somthing wrong?

Comment: thanks a lot , you are awesome , also if I may ask , do you have any experience in PyQt4 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Sorry.